# How to get IDs of selected cells in VTK python

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

I work on Programmable Filter which should change values of selected cells. 
How can I get IDs of selected cells to apply filter on them?

```
from paraview import vtk
pdi = self.GetPolyDataInput()
numCells = pdi.GetNumberOfCells()
for i in range(numCells): # <- ONLY FOR SELECTED CELLS?
    pdi.GetCellData().GetArray('force').SetValue(i, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently unsuported from a python programmable filter. you could however first use an ExtractSelection filter.